# In CPython, which structure is used to implement a user defined class and instances of the same

Tags: python, cpython

I'm digging inside the C implementation of Python, but until now I have been unable to identify which structure is used to implement a user defined class. I know that `PyTypeObject` must be involved, as it is for all Python's objects, with the global `PyType_Type`. Also `PySuper_Type` and `PyBaseObject_Type` must be used. But still, if this are the internal types used, which structure holds the user's part, which for sure must be allocated dynamically. And what about an instance of a user class. I looked inside of the **classobject.c** file, but all I can see there are types for `methods` and `instancemethod`. Nothing suggesting an answer to my uncertainties. I tried google, but apart from some great reading on Pyhton internals, I couldn't find anything more specific. I would appreciate any clarification in regard or at least a link to something to be read about it. Thanks to all who will help.

Comment: Have you gone through [Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html#extending-and-embedding-the-python-interpreter)?

Comment: System and user-defined classes use the same class mechanism.

Comment: @tdelaney Not all of it, but a good part and it seems to explain (very well) how to extend Python in C. I 'm interested in the mechanism behind class and instance creation at runtime. Can you point to a specific part of the resource you are mentioning, please?

Comment: Oh, I see. You are interested in how a class becomes an instance. I'm poking around to see who calls `tp_new`. Not sure if that will be fruitful.

Comment: @tdelaney Yes. But also I would  like to know where the data is stored, for both instance and class. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I'm not quite sure enough to make this the answer, but classes make themselves via the `tp_new` call. I think the base implementation is `cpython/Objects/typeobject.c::object_new`. The class definition itself is expressed with C structures in the code itself - so its just part of the executable's data section. Normally, instance information comes from the python heap. But a class could implement its own `tp_new` and get the allocated memory somewhere else. If so, it would also have to deal with reference counting and deletion.